# How to get hovered date in Highcharts spline?

Tags: highcharts

I need to integrate highcharts with table that contains related data. Each user's hover event should set particular background color to a table row. I don't know how can I get some information about hovered element in highcharts. I've created some demo to illustrate the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/677qt87g/1/)

```
plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                point:{
                    events:{
                        mouseOver: function(e) {
                            $('span').show().text('hover action').fadeOut();
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }
```

As you can see I've manged to get noticed about each hover event but I still don't know which point on charts was hovered. How can I get this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to the point's object in that event function via the `this` property.
To show the series name and the point index of the point you just hovered over you can do:
`$('span').show().text(this.series.name + ': ' + this.index).fadeOut();`